# Calculating the average with different conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have started to learn some basic usage in Power BI and need help in solving a problem.

Please see my table attached.

[image]

I want to calculate the average of the percentage of the last entry with the last "Status 1" for each ID. In my database there are some ID's in which the Status "Status 1" is just contained once (like ID 4) - I would like to exclude those ID's. Is that possible?

For this example it would be:

`(94 + 82 + 85) / 3 = 87`

I have started with trying to calculate the average of all "Percent" for all "Status 1".

```
Test Average 2 = 
CALCULATE ( 
    AVERAGEX(Tabelle1; Tabelle1[Percent]);   
    FILTER ( ALL ( Tabelle1 ); Tabelle1[Status]="Status 1" );
    ALL (Tabelle1)
)
```

How do I proceed? I don't know how to create the code with so many  conditions. I have tried to research the solution but gave up. I hope you can help me and would appreciate the help for a Coding beginner :)

Thanks in advance,
Jenny

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to the Power BI family!

Second, here is how I would approach your problem...

**1. Create a "DateTime" column**

Since we need to check for the latest entry, and presumably you want that checked based on date and time, it is easier if there is only one column to check).

In the ribbon, go to Modeling -> New Column.

[image: New Column button]

In the formula bar that pops up, enter the following formula. Power BI can recognize the date and time columns for what they are and since they are both elements of date/time, Power BI lets us do simple addition. The `- 1` in the formula is to account for the "day" that is associated with the time.

```
DateTime = [Date] + [Time] - 1
```

**2. Create Average Measure**

Here is the whole formula first and following is a breakdown piece by piece.

```
Last Percent Average = 
    VAR TargetStatus = "Status 1"
    VAR IDsWithMoreThanOneStatus1 = FILTER('Data', COUNTROWS(FILTER('Data', IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 && [ID] = EARLIER([ID]))) > 1)
    VAR LastStatus = FILTER(IDsWithMoreThanOneStatus1, IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 && [DateTime] >= MAXX(FILTER('Data', IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 && [ID] = EARLIER([ID])), [DateTime]))

RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUMX(LastStatus, [Percent]), COUNTROWS(LastStatus), BLANK())
```

The first chunk of the measure is defining variables. Variables are super useful and I would encourage you to at least take a quick look at them. Here's just [one article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/) on them.

The first variable is simply designating the target status (in case you ever want to change it). This variable is optional as if it will never change, you could just put the text into the other formulas.

```
    VAR TargetStatus = "Status 1"
```

The second variable filters the master list of data to only those IDs with more than one "Status 1" (excluding ID = 4 in this case). One of the keys with this variable is the `EARLIER` function. While it is horribly named (in my opinion), it is immensely useful. You can read the official documentation on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax).

Step by step through the variable: We want to filter the Data table... where the row count is greater than one... when we filter the table to include "Status 1" for the specified ID.

The `SEARCH` function will look at the entire string and tell us the starting position of our search string (TargetStatus). We need to wrap it in an `IFERROR` function to handle cases where TargetStatus does not show up in the [Status] value. Then we just check to see if the result is greater than 0 indicating that the TargetStatus is in the [Status] value.

```
VAR IDsWithMoreThanOneStatus1 = 
        FILTER(
            'Data',
            COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(
                    'Data',
                    IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 &&
                    [ID] = EARLIER([ID])
                )
            ) > 1
        )
```

The third variable filters the list from the second variable to capture the last "Status 1" for each ID. This uses the same thought process as the second variable: we want to filter the table (from the second variable) where the status = "Status 1" and the [DateTime] is greater than or equal to the max [DateTime] for all "Status 1" for the specified ID.

```
    VAR LastStatus = 
        FILTER(
            IDsWithMoreThanOneStatus1,
            IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 &&
            [DateTime] >= MAXX(
                FILTER(
                    'Data',
                    IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0 &&
                    [ID] = EARLIER([ID])
                ),
                [DateTime]
            )
        )
```

The `RETURN` keyword is just telling Power BI that we are done defining variables and that everything else in the formula defines the actual value that is returned for this measure.

```
RETURN
```

Lastly is the average itself. In this case, we'll use [`SUMX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) to sum up all of the [Percent]s from the third variable, and then divide it by the row count of the third variable. I would always recommend using the [`DIVIDE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax) function as it handles for dividing by 0 and other errors.

```
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            LastStatus,
            [Percent]
        ),
        COUNTROWS(LastStatus),
        BLANK()
    )
```

When it's all said and done, your measure will give the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working really well! It is still hard for me to understand the code, but I am working on understanding the interactions between the commands. 
I have encountered another difficulty. 
Is there a way to use wildcards for the first variable? I noticed in my datatable that sometimes there are more "status" in one cell. Like a cell sometimes looks like this: 

"Status 2, Status 1, Status 3"

Therefore the percent of this row will not be included into the calculations. :(

Thanks again @Joe. I really appreciate the help and work you put into your answer!

Comment: @Jenny98 Is there a specific piece of the code that you would like more detail around? I can edit my answer to provide more context if needed.
As for cells with multiple statuses, my formula should still work since it is filtering to Status = "Status 1". So even if the status includes 1, if there is anything else, it will get filtered out.

Comment: It is somehow not working for me. :( 

If I manipulate the dataset in a way that I change the Status in row 5 and 21 to "Status 1, Status 3" for example, then it doesn't get included into the calculations. My average turns to 82 instead of 87. 

I just have to get into the DAX in general. I still don't understand your useage of FILTER completely, but your help was already a great help. I don't want to waste any more of your time :)

Comment: @Jenny98 I am more than happy to help. Not only is it helping you, but others will see this and I learn new techniques along the way. All I ask is that if my answer solves your question, please mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: @Jenny98  I misread your first comment; I thought you wanted to exclude rows with multiple statuses. I've updated my answer to account for this. Basically, replace `[Status] = TargetStatus` with `IFERROR(SEARCH(TargetStatus, [Status]), -1) > 0` everywhere to get what you need.